# QTreeView items not selectable in Release mode

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I recently update my project to Qt version 4.8.7 and Visual Studio 2015.

I noticed that my `QTreeWidget` has difficulties in `Release` mode. The items are highlighting when the mouse hovers over, but actually selecting them requires many clicks. This is only the case in release mode, in debug mode, everything works fine.

See this very simple example

```
// add some test items
for (size_t t = 0; t < 4; t++)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->dataTreeWidget);
    item->setText(0, "level1");
    for (size_t c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* item2 = new QTreeWidgetItem(item);
        item2->setText(0, "level2");

        for (size_t r = 0; r < 4; r++)
        {
            QTreeWidgetItem* item3 = new QTreeWidgetItem(item2);
            item3->setText(0, "level3");
        }
    }
}
```

In release mode, after many (double) clicks on this item, it is only highlighted, not selected
[image]

In `debug` mode, the item is selected after a single click (as expected)

[image]

Is this a bug in Qt 4.8.7 (possibly an interaction with VS2015)? Is there a workaround?

Any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: In `release`, the required dependencies (DLLs) are there with the executable?

Comment: yes, otherwise the widget would not have loaded at all.